# angularjs reinit tinyMCE textarea content_css option

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

I have a question about the tinyMCE plugin in angularjs. 
I have a textarea

`<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="tinymceModel"></textarea>`

which should refresh the option `content_css` after a click on the button with another value. I know you can't really refresh the options, just kill and reinit but when I tried `tinyMCE.remove();` it is removing my textarea totally and then when I used `tinyMCE.init();` I can't reinit it, or am I just too confused?

Thx for any help :)

Quick fiddle-Sample what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/QuadroKnoX/k6tacgwn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have found a solution, just for the other people who need those information too:
I have used `$scope.$broadcast('$tinymce:refresh')` and for another purpose you can also use `$scope.$emit('$tinymce:refresh')` and put the "new" options in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a configuration object (an object holding all your tinymce configuration parameters) to the init function. Most important is a selector otherwise tinymce does not know for which html element to create an editor.

**Example:**

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
  ],
  toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image'
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it and that works so far BUT the actual textarea where it should initiate, has been removed by `tinymce.remove();` completely when triggering, so it cant be reinitiated. Do I have to use any params to prevent this?

Comment: the editor gets removed only - not the tinymce source element!

Comment: well my problem is that the angular tinymce is using e.g. `$scope.tinymceOptions = {}` to define the options and not `tinymce.init()` so I dont know if this concept works or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: unfortunatly i am not famliliar with angularjs